# How to add a user generated number of nested parameters?

Tags: c#

I want to find a way to have nested parameters by a user generated x-number of times.

An example of this is that I've made a few classes, lets call them `Milk()` and `Coffee()`

Lets say the user wants a coffee, with two milks, I'd make this object.

```
var item = new Milk(new Milk(new Coffee()))
```

what if the user wants a coffee, with only one milk? then it would look like this:

```
var item = new Milk(new Coffee());
```

Or just coffee on its own:

```
var item = new Coffee();
```

I want to find a way to make this. I've considered looping through the amount specified, but I have no idea how to continually add nested parameters and save it to the variable.

This is the code I have but I know it doesnt come close to what Im trying to do.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDownMilk.Value; i++)
{
    item += new Milk();
}
```

I know this wont work because its not adding to the parameter. I want it to be added to the specific parameter, nested.

EDIT:

There will be an messagebox stating an error if there isnt any `Coffee()`selected, also, its not possible for the item to have a Coffee within a Coffee, or a milk within a coffee.

so no

```
new Coffee(new Coffee())
```

or

```
new Coffee(new Milk())
```

It's always one coffee and zero or more milks wrapping it.

Comment: Are you looking for `IList<E>`?

Comment: @Progman Honestly, I have no clue as to what that is. I googled your question, and I didnt find exactly what could help me figure out by what you mean

Comment: The first thing to do is to make the problem more fully specified. Start with: what do you want to happen if the user wants *nothing*?  No milks, no coffees. Does this scenario ever come up?  If it does, you'll need to say what you want to have happen.  Second problem: Are you ever in a situation where there is a `Coffee` that is "outside" of something; that is, do you ever have `new Coffee(new Coffee())` or `new Coffee(new Milk())`?  Or is it always one coffee, and zero or more milks "wrapping" it?

Comment: @EricLippert I've updated the description as you asked.

Comment: after your edits it seems the the example of milk and coffe wasn't a good choice, as it doesn't make a difference if it's milk in the coffee or coffee in the milk... (yes, one might argue the first one is a "espresso", the second a "latte"..) So, what's the real usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, this is a very strange way to represent milks and coffees, but let's take you at your word that this is sensible in your business domain.

The way to do what you want is: first, since the return can be either a `Milk` or a `Coffee`, you need to somehow represent that in the type system.  You could make a common base class, or a common interface. Let's suppose you have a common base class:

```
abstract class Beverage {}
sealed class Coffee : Beverage {}
sealed class Milk : Beverage {}
```

Once you have the types sorted out, start with the signature:

```
public static Beverage MakeCoffee(int milks)
{ /* a miracle happens */ }
```

Now try to fill in the miracle.  What happens?  Well, you start with a coffee:

```
public static Beverage MakeCoffee(int milks)
{
    Beverage b = new Coffee();
```

And now we wrap it in some number of milks:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < milks; i += 1)
        b = new Milk(b);
    return b;
}
```

And we're done.

- **Exercise**: Implement the constructor on `Milk`
- **Exercise**: Implement `public override string ToString()` on `Milk` and `Coffee` such that you get back out the string `Milk(Milk(Coffee))` when you call it on a coffee with two milks.
- **Exercise**: Now do `Tea`, `Cream` and `Lemon`.
- **Exercise**: (Hard!) How would you implement the rule that `Cream` or `Milk` can wrap `Coffee` but you can't put `Cream` and `Lemon` into `Tea` at the same time?

Comment: Let's just stick our `ToString()` method on `Beverage`: `return Child == null ? GetType().Name : $"{GetType().Name}({Child.ToString()})";` .  Here, `Child` is a protected property (or field) of type `Beverage`.  Probably a virtual property is ideal, in case you want to have inheritors use a backing field of specific type.

Answer (score 2):

Wait, wait, wait - stop, slow down.

First, I need to explain what you're actually doing with that code:

```
var item = new Milk(new Milk(new Coffee()))
```

... this is creating a new Coffee.  Fine so far.  And then it's using that new Coffee as an argument for the constructor to create a new Milk.  And then it's using *that* new Milk object as an argument for creating *another* milk object.

Okay, so let's back up several steps.  You talk about how to know how many milks the person wants with their coffee, right?

Try this on for size:

```
class Coffee
{
    int numberOfMilks;
}
```

Now, if you want a coffee with two milks, you could just use this:

```
Coffee order = new Coffee();
order.numberOfMilks = 2;
```

Make sense?  You don't need to create a "Milk Object" or "Multiple Milk Objects" - the *number* of milks is just a property of the coffee they're ordering.

**EDIT: Okay, for the OP and anyone needing an answer to the question as-is?**  First, give a brief prayer of forgiveness to the gods of code quality.  (Seriously, I'm having trouble figuring out why this would be what you have to do, but... oh well.)

There's no difference between:

```
Milk a = new Milk(new Milk());
```

and

```
var intermediate = new Milk();
Milk a = new Milk(intermediate);
```

After all, in the first version, it's creating a new Milk object... and then feeding that into a second Milk object's constructor.  The only difference in the second version is that it breaks it into two commands instead of train-car'ing them together.

Okay, so that should hopefully light the way.  Because you can always do something like:

```
Milk nestedMilks = new Milk();
for (int i = 1; i < nestedAmount; i++)
{
    nestedMilks = new Milk(nestedMilks);
}
Coffee final = new Coffee(nestedMilks);
```

... you *can* do something like that.  *Should* is another thing altogether.  (Not sure you on earth having all those instances be nested like that makes sense.)

Comment: true, til that day one user wants one shot cow milk and one shot soja...and a bit of foam on top.

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, but I have to do it this way, its not just for the simple coffee example I've given to you, its just so I can understand to do it for a more complex problem. I actually have to do it this way, if I didn't I wouldn't have been looking for this

Answer (score 0):

a very simple, basic implementation:

```
// have a base class (or an interface), that Milk, Coffee, etc derive from (or implement)
// the main thing is the abstraction part.
public abstract class Ingredient 
{
   // define anything common in here, and/or something all subclasses MUST implement
}

// let Milk, Coffe, etc extend that class
public class Milk : Ingredient
{
     // special fields, properties, methods for Milk
}
```

now somewhere else you can make use of a generic List

```
List<Ingredient> ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
ingredients.Add(new Coffee(Coffe.Types.DECAF));  // arguments just as example
ingredients.Add(new Milk(Milk.Types.ZEROLACTOSE));
ingredients.Add(new Milk(Milk.Types.REGULAR));
```

In your case it could be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDownMilk.Value; i++)
{
    ingredients.Add(new Milk());
}
```